# Having trouble adding java to HTML, What am I missing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Trying to do something simple here. I'm a beginner so this is all kind of new. The code works in JSFiddle but if I save it as a .html file and attempt to upload it/open it the script no longer works.

Jquery script im trying to use -

```js
$('#getdata').on('click', function () {
    var formCategory = $('#categories').val();
    var formAddress = $('#address').val();
    var formTown = $('#town').val();
    var formInfo = $('#info').val();

    $('#form_Alert').val('' + formTown + ' |' + formCategory + '| ' + formAddress + ' ' + formInfo);
});
```

**What it's looking like when I'm adding it to HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC"-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    <html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<head>
<center><Title>BNN CAD</Title></center>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
$('#getdata').on('click', function () {
    var formCategory = $('#categories').val();
    var formAddress = $('#address').val();
    var formTown = $('#town').val();
    var formInfo = $('#info').val();
 $('#form_Alert').val('' + formTown + ' |' + formCategory + '| ' + formAddress + ' ' + formInfo);
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<p>
    <label>Town:</label>
    <select id="town">
        <option>Dundalk</option>
        <option>Edgemere</option>
        <option>Sparrows Point</option>
        <option>Essex</option>
        <option>Middle River</option>
        <option>Cockeysville</option>
        <option>Parkville</option>
        <option>White Marsh</option>
        <option>Woodlawn</option>
        <option>Lansdowne</option>
        <option>Catonsville</option>
        <option>Arbutus</option>
        <option>Monkton</option>
        <option>Sparks</option>
    </select>
    <p>
        <label>Incident Type:</label>
        <select id="categories">
            <option>SHOOTING</option>
            <option>STABBING</option>
            <option>ARMED ROBBERY</option>
            <option>ROBBERY</option>
            <option>SERIOUS ASSAULT</option>
            <option>HOME INVASION</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>
        <label>Address:</label>
        <input type="text" id="address">
    </p>
    <p></p>
    <p>
        <label>Details:</label>
        <input type="text" id="info">
    </p>
    <p>
        <input type="Submit" value="Preview Alert" id="getdata">
    </p>
    <p><b> Alert:</p>
    <textarea id="form_Alert"></textarea>
    </html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by **java** here?

Comment: java != javascript.  Not even a little :-)

Comment: You will have to use a dom ready handler... when your script is executed the target element is not yet added to the dom

Comment: If you save it as a file and attempt to load the file directly into a browser (without a web server) you may run into security restrictions.

Comment: Sorry, Meant javascript I guess! I will try and do this with a web server and see if the problem is solved.

Comment: Just by using a web server problem won't be solved. Either having dom ready event or by placing your script at the bottom of your html would solve it.

Comment: Thanks, missed your response. Was looking at Eric J's.Will try both

Comment: Java is to JavaScript as Car is to Carpet. Please get it right.

Comment: I already corrected myself, Please read up.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is executed before the target elements are added to the dom, so the event handler is not added to the element.

So the solution is to add the event handler registration in a [dom ready](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) handler like

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script language="JavaScript">
    jQuery(function ($) {
        $('#getdata').on('click', function () {
            var formCategory = $('#categories').val();
            var formAddress = $('#address').val();
            var formTown = $('#town').val();
            var formInfo = $('#info').val();
            $('#form_Alert').val('' + formTown + ' |' + formCategory + '| ' + formAddress + ' ' + formInfo);
        });
    })
</script>
```

In jsfiddle by default the script is added in a `window.onload` handler(second dropdown under `Frameworks & Extensions` in the left panel) that is why it is working. If you change it to `No Wrap - in <head>` it won't work there either.